# Debian: Routing Table and Two Interfaces

Tags: networking, debian, routing, network-interface

I've a Debian machine with this network scenario:

1. **eth0** - Internet Connection via local Router (172.20.1.x)
2. **ppp0** - Dial-up to a network without internet (10.x.x.x)

I've set pppd so it won't add any default routes to my routing table and my routing table looks like this after booting up the system:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         172.20.1.1      0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.64.64.64     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 ppp0
172.20.1.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

With this configuration I'm able to **ping google.com**, however I can't get to any machine with IP's like 10.0.0.1 or 10.0.0.2 etc...

Trying to fix this (with my poor knowledge) I modified my `/etc/network/interfaces` file to:

```
auto lo

iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet dhcp

auto ppp0 
iface ppp0 inet ppp
    pre-up sleep 5
    provider vfp
    post-up  /sbin/route add -net 10.0.0.0 netmask 255.0.0.0 gw 10.64.64.64
    pre-down  /sbin/route del -net 10.0.0.0 netmask 255.0.0.0 gw 10.64.64.64
```

But apparently the command `post-up  /sbin/route add -net 10.0.0.0 netmask 255.0.0.0 gw 10.64.64.64` that should add the route to make it work is not taking effect—nothing is changing on the routing table.

What am I missing? / How can I fix this? Thank you ;)

**PS: If i run `route add -net 10.0.0.0 netmask 255.0.0.0 gw 10.64.64.64` after the system boots up I'm able to ping both google.com and 10.0.0.1 from the system.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to add or remove routes for `ppp` connections I don't use the `interfaces` file. I add scripts in `/etc/ppp/ip-up.d` and `/etc/ppp/ip-down.d` respectively instead. You simply can place scripts there with your `route` commands.

Comment: Testing now... Thx for the feedback ;)

Comment: Working just fine ;) ty!