# how to connect both wifi and ethernet at the same time in kali linux

Tags: linux

I am using kali linux 2.0 and i am connected to both ethernet and wifi at the same. Wifi (from TPlink router) has internet access and ethernet is used to configure mikrotik router. but i am facing problem while browsing internet. I need internet access and mikrotik access simultaneously.I am accessing mikrotik with winbox through wine.
I have given manual ip:192.168.1.20/24 for lan and dhcp enable for wifi.

Comment: You'll need to provide more information about the interface configuration. Most likely you have a default gateway on both interfaces.  It should only be on the internet interface.

Comment: I used static IP for ethernet and DHCP for wifi connection. Also both are on different network.

Comment: And default gateway?

Comment: static ip 192.168.1.20/24
gateway:192.168.1.1

wifi is on dhcp

Comment: This question has been asked many times before,  for instance https://superuser.com/questions/725935/default-route-in-debian-with-two-interfaces and https://superuser.com/questions/533374/debian-routing-table-and-two-interfaces,  or even here, https://superuser.com/questions/533374/debian-routing-table-and-two-interfaces

Answer (score 0):

You are being given a default gateway by your wifi connection, this lets you get to the internet.

You are also setting a default gateway on your ethernet connection, effectively telling your machine that the internet is out your ethernet connection.

Remove the default gateway from the lan connection (ethernet).

Comment: if i remove default gateway from lan i will be unable to login mikrotik.

Comment: Please edit your question and include the ip addresses of everything

Comment: wifi :
ip:172.16.100.200
gateway:172.16.100.1

lan:
ip:192.168.1.20

Comment: So there is no ip on the mikrotik router? Please [edit] your question too add additional information

Comment: initially there is no ip and to access the router via lan you only need mac of the router but there should be ip for pc lan.
FYI, i tested the method you suggested on mac book it worked but it doesn't on kali linux.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include additional information.  This answer does not suggest removing the IP of the LAN, but the default gateway setting.